# Python Plotly barchart - how do I add a horizontal line on the chart?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly

I have a barchart as displayed;
[image]

The code that produced this is as follows;

```py
def create_bar_chart(_dict, _title, _title_text, titles, image_paths):
    _fig = go.Figure()
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict(score=_dict.values(), trait=_dict.keys()))
    _image = f"{_title_text}_sm.jpg"
    _width=600
    _height=400

    _fig = px.bar(df, x="trait", y="score")
    _fig.update_layout(xaxis_title=None)
```

I want to put a horizontal line (with a width the same as the bar) for each bar which will indicate the average value. This value may be above the bar or within the bar. So for example with analytical thinking the average value may be 0.2 or 0.4, so I need a horizontal line with that score. How do I do this?

Comment: Do you means that this horizontal line marks the position of the average value for each bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is my interpretation of the demand in the question, where a horizontal line of the same width as each bar is drawn at the height of some average score

```py
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data_dict = {
    'trait': ['analytical thinking', 'cognitive processes', 'certainty', 'insight', 'abstract', 'concrete'],
    'score': [0.35, 0.15, 0.02, 0.05, 0.42, 0.2]
}

X_COUNT = len(data_dict['trait'])
# The x-axis of bar chart is divided evenly by the number of x elements.
# This width is not necessarily the bar width, but the entire width for
# x element, which includes the bar and the two gaps on either side.
TOTAL_WIDTH = 1 / X_COUNT
# Set the gap between bars. It is a percentage of TOTAL_WIDTH. In other
# words, if we have TOTAL_WIDTH = 1 and BAR_GAP = 0.2, then the bar width
# would be 0.8 and the gaps between two bars would be 0.2
BAR_GAP = 0.2

fig = px.bar(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict), x='trait', y='score')
fig.update_layout(
    width=600,
    height=400,
    bargap=BAR_GAP,
)

# The relative starting position of each bar (i.e., considering the width
# of the chart as 1)
bar_starts = np.cumsum([TOTAL_WIDTH] * X_COUNT) - 1 / X_COUNT

averages = [0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.02, 0.35, 0.25]  # whatever average score to plot
for bs, ave in zip(bar_starts, averages):
    line_st = bs + TOTAL_WIDTH * BAR_GAP / 2
    fig.add_shape(
        type='line',
        x0=line_st,
        y0=ave,
        x1=line_st + TOTAL_WIDTH * (1 - BAR_GAP),
        y1=ave,
        xref='paper',  # relative x position
        yref='y'  # exact y position as shown on the y-axis
    )
fig.show()
```

The plot looks like this

[image]

### Limitation

This solution does not work if the plot needs to zoom in or out. The line size does not scale with the zoom.

Answer (score 0):

Using plotly's development features, it may be possible to accurately determine the coordinates of the width of each bar and draw a line. Please try the following code to see the structure of the dictionary. `full_fig = fig.full_figure_for_development();print(full_fig)` I have added a red horizontal line using the marker symbol horizontal line type. The length of the line is adjusted by the size of the marker symbol.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df_Asia = px.data.gapminder().query('continent == "Asia"')
df = df_Asia.groupby(['country'])['lifeExp'].agg('mean').to_frame('mean').merge(
               df_Asia[['country','year','lifeExp']].query('year == 2007').set_index('country'), left_index=True, right_index=True)

import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df.index, y=df['lifeExp'], name='lifeExp'))
# mode='lines'
#fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(mode='lines', x=df.index, y=df['mean'], line_color='red', name='mean'))
# mode='markers'
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(mode='markers', x=df.index, y=df['mean'], name='mean', marker=dict(symbol='line-ew-open', color='red', size=14)))
fig.update_xaxes(range=[-1, len(df)])

fig.show()
```

[image]