# Marker width on bars in Python Plotly subplots

Tags: python, plotly

I'd like the marker lines on the bars of my subplots to be determined automatically, as the full width of each bar.  Currently, they are only a portion of the width:
[subplots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlGkv.png)

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

subplots = ['A','B','C','D']
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2, subplot_titles=subplots)
layout = go.Layout(
    barmode='stack',
    height=1000,
    width=1000,
    bargap=0.2,
)
fig.update_layout(layout)

directions = ['north','east','south','west']
levels = ['top','middle','bottom']

row = 1
col = 1
for subplot in subplots:
    for direction in directions:
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Bar(
                x=levels,
                y=np.random.randint(20, size=3),
            ),
            row=row,
            col=col,
        ) ,
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            mode='markers',
            x=levels,
            y=np.random.randint(20, size=3) + 2,
            marker={
                'symbol':   'line-ew-open',
                'size':     24,
                'color':    'black',
            }
        ),
        row=row,
        col=col,
    )
    ## move on
    if col == 2:
        row += 1
        col = 1
    else:
        col += 1

fig.show()
```

As per the answer of **r-beginners** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77218192/python-plotly-barchart-how-do-i-add-a-horizontal-line-on-the-chart), it seems to be possible to do this using `fig.full_figure_for_development()`, in a way which adjusts for zooming.  But I can't see how to extract this.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `fig.add_shape(type="line")` you can insert scalable lines to your figure. With this alteration of your original code you'll get lines on each bar in all the subplots.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

column_width = .6
subplots = ['A','B','C','D']
directions = ['north','east','south','west']
levels = ['top','middle','bottom']

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2, subplot_titles=subplots)
layout = go.Layout(
    barmode='stack',
    height=1000,
    width=1000,
    bargap=1-column_width,
)
fig.update_layout(layout)

row = 1
col = 1
for number, subplot in enumerate(subplots):
    for direction in directions:
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Bar(
                x=levels,
                y=np.random.randint(20, size=3),
            ),
            row=row,
            col=col,
        )
    # add marker lines
    bars_y = [bar.y for bar in fig.data[number*4:number*4+4]]
    for pos,level in enumerate(levels):
        y_pos = sum([a[pos] for a in bars_y])/4
        fig.add_shape(type="line",
                      x0=pos-column_width/2,
                      x1=pos+column_width/2,
                      y0=y_pos,
                      y1=y_pos,
                      row=row,
                      col=col)
    ## move on
    if col == 2:
        row += 1
        col = 1
    else:
        col += 1

fig.show(renderer="browser")
```

The result will be something like this.

[image: bar graph with lines]

These are the alternatives that I have checked. First was `fig.add_hline`, however this produces a line width infinite length which is not what you are looking for. Sexond, adding markers has no argument for length. Lastly, after digging through `fig.full_figure_for_development()` you can find the `xrange` in `xaxis` part of the layout. However this is the same range as you set.

Comment: That's very helpful.  Thanks a lot for taking the time to look at alternatives, and for giving a solution—just what I needed.